# non native android app - check if push notification disabled in application manager

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on an android web app. I am using PhoneGap Push Plugin to receive push notifications on device. I need to track if push notifications have been disabled for my app in the application manager settings. How do I achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you have already implemented or what you think is hard about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check in .java class whether the notification is enabled or no 
I am posting reference java code for check whether notification is enabled or not

```
public class NotificationsUtils {
private static final String CHECK_OP_NO_THROW = "checkOpNoThrow";
private static final String OP_POST_NOTIFICATION = "OP_POST_NOTIFICATION";
public static boolean isNotificationEnabled(Context context) {

    AppOpsManager mAppOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);

    ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();

    String pkg = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

    int uid = appInfo.uid;

    Class appOpsClass = null; /* Context.APP_OPS_MANAGER */

    try {

        appOpsClass = Class.forName(AppOpsManager.class.getName());

        Method checkOpNoThrowMethod = appOpsClass.getMethod(CHECK_OP_NO_THROW, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class);

        Field opPostNotificationValue = appOpsClass.getDeclaredField(OP_POST_NOTIFICATION);
        int value = (int)opPostNotificationValue.get(Integer.class);

        return ((int)checkOpNoThrowMethod.invoke(mAppOps,value, uid, pkg) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jack. But I am not using android sdk. It's a phonegap application. Is there a way to interpret GCM server response to know if notification was sent to a device where notification has been disabled?

Comment: But you are able to call native function through cordova custom plugin and able to check this

Comment: I have switched off notification on device for my app. Now when I send push notification to this device GCM server reports it as success. 

Is there a way to interpret GCM server response to know if notification was sent to a device where notification has been disabled?

Comment: @nexus it's device facility to ignore gcm message , google service send message to respected device but when device receive message from restricted gcm app will remove that notification automatically without displaying it to notification bar